# How to handle user settings?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to save a list of key-value pairs for a user in sections.

```
<section="SomeFoo">
   <key="foo" value="bar" />
</Section>
```

I want to read, add, edit and remove dynamically entries and sections. Also I want to get all keys of an section.

Something like

```
config.Read("SomeFoo", "foo");              // Read key foo from section SomeFoo
config.Read("SomeFoo");                     // Get all keys from section SomeFoo
config.Add("SomeFoo", "foo", "bar");        // Add key to section SomeFoo, key is foo, value is bar
config.Edit("SomeFoo", "foo", "newValue");  // Edit existing key foo from section SomeFoo and overwrite current value with newValue
config.Remove("SomeFoo", "foo");            // Remove key foo from section SomeFoo
config.Remove("SomeFoo");                   // Remove section SomeFoo
```

I've tried to use AppSettings and SectionGroups. See [here](https://gist.github.com/SchadLucas/6124221). But it seems I can't add dynamically keys to a SectionGroup. Is that even possible? If it's not possible what alternatives do I have?

It is important that settings are saved for each user. `%appdata%\foo\bar.config`.

Comment: i used [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx) once to make my own config section

Comment: although I don't think this is best for your scenario.  You should use some sort of data structure if you are saving data for each user.  Not the config file.

Comment: This comes off to me as a misuse/abuse of a configuration file -- have you considered using a local database, such as a SQL compact database to handle saving your end user configuration and settings?

Comment: @ George Johnston, this was my second idea when I noticed that there seems to be no way to use Configuration Manager to achieve my goal. But I thought there must be a ready way for me in .NET

Comment: Use the PrivateProfile API to read/write to an .ini file, or create your own custom .xml format file.  Either method is very easy to do.  Then store the file in the user account \AppData\Local\your_app\ for local users or \AppData\Roaming\your_app\ for network roaming users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `ConfigurationElementCollection`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection(v=vs.80).aspx